# How to install qtquick 2.0 and ubuntu components 0.1?

Tags: command-line, qt-creator

I am facing this problem while making a currency converter program in qt creator.

The program is as follows:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 0.1

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: units.gu(60)
    height: units.gu(80)
    color: "lightgray"

    property real margins: units.gu(2)
    property real buttonWidth: units.gu(9)

    Label {
       id: title
       ItemStyle.class: "title"
       text: i18n.tr("Currency Converter")
       height: contentHeight + root.margins
       anchors {
           left: parent.left
           right: parent.right
           top: parent.top
       }
     }
    }
```

And error says:

```
Starting /usr/bin/qmlviewer -I /usr/lib/qt4/imports /home/shri/CurrencyConverter/CurrencyConverter.qml
Qml debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment!
file:///home/shri/CurrencyConverter/CurrencyConverter.qml:1:1: module "QtQuick" version 2.0 is not installed 
     import QtQuick 2.0 
     ^
```

Comment: Have you followed the instructions to [install Qt5](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/#step-get-toolkit)?